# Bootstrap dropdown extended dropdowns (nested)

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I was wondering if it was possible to extend the dropdowns. I think you will understand what I mean once I describe it but I just don't know the name for it. So after you open the initial dropdown. You may have child elements that may open another dropdown-esque menu, in this case to the right, which may provide more precise options. So for instance...

```
Menu
  v
option1 -> precise1
option2    precise2
           precise3
```

There doesn't seem to be anything in the components documentation describing this behaviour.

Comment: @HermLuna I'm more or less asking if there's any inbuilt functionality that exists for the component already. Otherwise I may as well just write my own dropdown.

Comment: I don't think bootstrap offers something like that. Maybe some bootstrap plugins. Since, you can write your own. Why don't try it? If you found difficulties. Share. So, someone can help you. In this case, this is more about researching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something I wrote for another project.

HTML

```
    <div class="dropdown">
    <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#" href="#">
        Menu <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
        <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Option 2</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Precise 1 </a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Precise 2</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a href="#">More precise </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Precise 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Precise 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/meuequalsd/pen/mAorxE)